# Discord JS Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to remove some roles and then assign a new role to a member depending on the index. Doing it like I did in this code works when trying to access `member` via the `message` object but not vie a cached member object. The first 6 lines are just to get an array of user id's from a database (which works).
Here is the code:

```
    const users = await verifiedUsers.find({});

    const userMap = {};
    users.forEach((user) => {
        userMap[user.ign] = user;
    });
    for (let user in userMap) {
      let userid = userMap[user].memberid
      let membe = guild.members.cache.get(userid)
      let index = userMap[user].customstats.index
      membe.roles.remove("964653007117627453");
      membe.roles.remove("964652871113142282");
      membe.roles.remove("964652446154633256");
      var role = ""
      if (index < 100) {
        role = "964653007117627453"
      }
      else if (index >= 100 && index < 200) {
          role = "964652871113142282"
      }
      else if (index >= 200 && index < 300) {
          role = "964652446154633256"
      }
      else if (index >= 400) {
          role = "964651864052334683"
      }
      membe.roles.add(role)
    }
```

The error:

```
      membe.roles.remove("964653007117627453");
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')
    at refreshAllRanks (C:\Users\nobyp\OneDrive\Dokumente\GitHub\FDS-Bot\counters\api-count.ts:102:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: There's no member with that id in the cache, hence `membe` (where's the `r`? o.O) is `undefined`.

Comment: There is a member with that id in the cache, I can actually log the ```membe``` object and it's perfectly fine!

Comment: Obviously not when `membe.roles.remove(...)` is executed.

Comment: I tried it again and it definetly is a valid id.

Answer (score 1):

1. It may cause when the user with given id is not in the guild.
2. It may cause when you try to do it using `cache.get()`.
   I would suggest using `fetch()` to get user, channel or guild.